# Testing Doorkeeper oAuth2 for Zapier App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, zapier, doorkeeper

#### Question

How would we test a Doorkeeper oauth2 implementation for a Zapier cli app?

#### Background

I have a Rails 3 app. I am trying to create a Zapier client for the application and I decided to use OAuth. Thus I configured doorkeeper to generate a JWT. All looks good, I am able to authorize and get token using the redirects.

I am not sure how to test the app purely through the console. Wouldn't it require some way to authorize using username/password?

I got an app generated from the template with some minor differences.

```
  it('can fetch an access token', (done) => {
    const bundle = {
      inputData: {
        // In production, Zapier passes along whatever code your API set in the query params when it redirects
        // the user's browser to the `redirect_uri`
        code: 'one_time_code',
        subdomain: 'ducks'
      },
      environment: {
        CLIENT_ID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
      }
    };

    appTester(App.authentication.oauth2Config.getAccessToken, bundle)
      .then((result) => {
        result.access_token.should.eql('a_token');
        result.refresh_token.should.eql('a_refresh_token');
        done();
      })
      .catch(done);
  });
```

results in something like this:

```
  1) oauth2 app can fetch an access token:
     Got 401 calling POST https://ducks.<domain>.com/oauth/token, triggering auth refresh.
What happened:
  Starting POST request to https://ducks.<domain>.com/oauth/token
  Received 401 code from https://ducks.<domain>.com/oauth/token after 1425ms
  Received content "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, include"
  Got 401 calling POST https://ducks.<domain>.com/oauth/token, triggering auth refresh.
```

Which should be because the user is not logged in the request made in the test console...

How can I make the user login? Or should the tests be changed?